# Count user groups by file extension from ls listing

Tags: bash, shell

I have to do this exercise:

> Create a script that lists the type of regular files contained in the directory by classifying them by extension and lists for each extension the groups that have at least one file with that extension and the number of files they own.

For example if this is the file

```
-rw-------  2   utente1   staff   4096  2007-02-10   14:28   doc1.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1   utente1   staff    102  2007-02-11   02:05   doc2.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1   utente2   users   3145  2007-01-16   01:48   rel.tex
-rw-------  1   utente2   users    268  2007-01-16   10:37   song1.mp3
-rw-r--r--  4   utente3   staff   4096  2006-04-28   19:29   text1.tex
-rw-r--r--  1   utente3   staff     11  2007-05-02   12:10   text2.tex
```

In output I have to have

```
.tex: users 1 staff 2
.pdf: staff 2
.mp3: users 1
```

I did this but it doesn't work for me, it prints values not present in the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

groups=$(awk ' {print $4}' group.txt | sort | uniq)

echo .tex:
for group in $groups
do
    awk -v gr=$group ' ($4==gr && $1~"^-") {somma=somma+$5; num=num+1}; END {if(somma!=0) {print gr,num,"("somma")"}}' group.txt

done

 

echo .pdf:
for group in $groups
do
    awk -v gr=$group ' ($4==gr && $1~"^-") {somma=somma+$5; num=num+1}; END {if(somma!=0) {print gr,num,"("somma")"}}' group.txt 
done

 

echo .mp3:
for group in $groups
do
    awk -v gr=$group ' ($4==gr && $1~"^-") {somma=somma+$5; num=num+1}; END {if(somma!=0) {print gr,num,"("somma")"}}' group.txt
done
```

Comment: One more reason to learn Awk. You should be able to complete this yourself in less than an hour, including reading an Awk tutorial. Basically, collect the results in an associative array where the key is the extension and the value is the count you have seen so far, then in the `END` block report the numbers. You'll need a secondary associative array to collect the extension and group mappings.

Comment: Tangentially, [generally try to avoid parsing `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) though of course if that's what was given in the assignment, there's no way here to avoid that.

Comment: @tripleee okay so it's not possible to fix the above, I have to use array as?

Comment: Of course it can be fixed, but reading the same file repeatedly is horrible.

Comment: @tripleee okay in case you can fix it how can i fix it?

Comment: I have not spent any time debugging this; neither, apparently, have you.

Comment: @tripleee It's this one that's incorrect: awk -v gr=staff '$4==gr && $1~"^-" {sum=sum+$5; number=number+1}; END {if(sum!=0) {print gr,num,"("sum")"}}' group.txt

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I don't understand where should I put it?

Comment: The `-printf` solution requires GNU `find`, though. Given that the assignment provides an `ls` listing (not necessarily access to the actual files) this doesn't really work here.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub but I don't use the ls command but the group.txt file

Comment: In your group.txt file are file extensions `.txt` and `.tex` to be treated as the same file type?  (If not, then I am not sure how the `.tex: users 1 staff 2` portion of your expected output could be generated)

Comment: @j_b no sorry txt shouldn't have been there now I correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in comments parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea. But as you are asked to do so... If you use `awk` it is really a pity to not use its full power. Example with GNU `awk` that supports multi-dimensions arrays:

```
awk '
  /^-/ {
    i = match($NF, /\.[^.]*$/)
    e = substr($NF, i)
    g = $4
    c[e][g]++
  }
  END {
    for(e in c) {
      printf("%s:", e)
      for(g in c[e])
        printf(" %s %d", g, c[e][g])
      print ""
    }
  }' group.txt
```

But if you insist on a bash solution why not a pure bash one (with a recent enough bash that supports associative arrays)?

```
declare -A cnt=() ext=() grp=()

while read -ra f; do
  [[ "${f[0]}" == -* ]] || continue
  e="${f[-1]##*.}"
  g="${f[3]}"
  ext["$e"]=1
  grp["$g"]=1
  (( cnt["$e $g"] += 1 ))
done < group.txt 

for e in "${!ext[@]}"; do
  printf '.%s:' "$e"
  for g in "${!grp[@]}"; do
    if [[ -v cnt["$e $g"] ]]; then
      printf ' %s %d' "$g" "${cnt["$e $g"]}"
    fi
  done
  printf '\n'
done
```

Comment: so fixing what i did above (at the beginning of the file) is not possible?

Comment: Sure, we could try to fix it but 1) in what you try the extensions are hard-wired instead of being extracted from the file; 2) except for the `echo` commands what you do does not depend on the file extensions (which contradict what you explain); 3) the `somma` stuff is not part of your requirements; 4) the expected output you show is different from what you are trying to achieve; 5) your 3 `for` loops are identical, why do you think they should produce different results? That's a lot of issues. So it is probably better to fix all this at once.